# Java Junit - Expected Exception to be thrown but nothing is thrown

Tags: java, exception, junit

"Expected exception to be thrown but nothing" is thrown causing a failure in my test case. How to resolve this. I want to throw an exception if the number is negative while finding a factorial,

Test File:

```java
public void testCalculateFactorialWithOutOfRangeException(){

  Factorial factorial = new Factorial();
    assertThrows(OutOfRangeException.class,
     () -> factorial.calculateFactorial(-12));

}
```

Code file:

```java
public class Factorial {
    public String calculateFactorial(int number) {
        //If the number is less than 1
        try {
            if (number < 1)
                throw new OutOfRangeException("Number cannot be less than 1");
            if (number > 1000)
                throw new OutOfRangeException("Number cannot be greater than 1000");

        } catch (OutOfRangeException e) {

        }
    }
}

public class OutOfRangeException extends Exception {
    public OutOfRangeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be a success but it is causing a failure

Comment: Are your brackets correct? It seems like the catch block is outside of the calculateFactorial method

Comment: why is there a `catch` block? the formatting/indentation is difficult to follow, but it looks like you throw `OutOfRangeException` in two places, then catch `OutOfRangeException` and swallow it – that is, the caller would never see a `OutOfRangeException`. your test is expecting an exception to be thrown, but your code will never throw one out of the method.

Comment: This code will not even compile. Fix compile errors first.

Comment: Side note: [`1000! = 4.023872601×10^2567](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).  Are you really planning on performing that large a calculation?

Comment: @jhell Yeah!! The code is correctly bracketed. I tried my best to post the necessary part only.

Comment: @mentallurg I think you are right but somehow the code actually gets compiled.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes! That's the plan, I tried the use of array to compute this large number. Maybe I will try linked list in the coming future to extend the range to 10k. Meanwhile, if you got any ideas to solve that please do share with me.. RIP Ram :)

Comment: @Akash: *but somehow the code actually gets compiled* - that is not true. Gets compiled what you have on your computer. But what you posted here cannot be compiled. It has 3 compile errors. That's why check your code here and post exactly what you have on your computer.

Comment: @Akash - If you were using a mutable to integer array to calculate the value, that's going to be less memory intensive than using `String`.  For that matter, `BigInteger` (which essentially wraps an immutable array) would also use less memory.  There are various ways to make the calculation more time efficient, which may also make it more space efficient (since the fewer calculations performed the less memory is used with immutable structures).

Comment: If you want to investigate why a test is failing, you should use a debugger.

Answer (score 9):

Your test is fine, the problem is with your code that does not throw the exception, or more correctly- throws and catches it.

Remove the `catch (OutOfRangeException e)` clause from the method and add `throws OutOfRangeException` and then your test will pass

Comment: Thank you for your help. this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a test case like below when your method throws an exception.

```
@Test(expected =OutOfRangeException.class)
public void testCalculateFactorialWithOutOfRangeException() throws OutOfRangeException{

    Factorial factorial = new Factorial();
   factorial.calculateFactorial(-12);
}
```

However in your case, you are not throwing an exception in class but it is handled in the catch block, if you throw an exception in your method then it will work.

```
class Factorial {

    public String calculateFactorial(int number) throws OutOfRangeException{

        //If the number is less than 1

        if(number < 1)
            throw new OutOfRangeException("Number cannot be less than 1");
        if(number > 1000)
            throw new OutOfRangeException("Number cannot be greater than 1000");


        return "test";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious time by answering this.

Comment: Thanks Akash glad to know it helped